# Why is [over.call.object]/1 written like this in the Standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[over.call.object]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.call.object#1)

> If the postfix-expression `E` in the function call syntax evaluates to
>   a class object of type “cv `T`”, then the set of candidate functions
>   includes at least the function call operators of `T`. The function
>   call operators of `T` are obtained by ordinary lookup of the name
>   `operator()` in the context of `(E).operator()`.

I can understand what this paragraph is saying but why did they use the terms "in the context of `(E).operator()`", instead of, "`in the context of class T`"? That is, my understanding of the text above is that the name `operator()` will be looked up in the context of class `T`, where the *postfix-expression* `E` evaluates as an object of type `T`.

Comment: The "at least" indicates strongly that more than just the `()` operators of `T` can be present in the set of candidate functions. I fail to see how that can happen though.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, You can also have a conversion operator to something like a function pointer.

Comment: @chris: Thanks. I don't grok this fully yet but then, it's a complex subject.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, No kidding. I tested that rather than look for wording, but it doesn't let you do a conversion to a different class with a function call operator, so I'm a bit more curious now.

Comment: @chris In fact, [the very next paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.call.object#2), starting with "In addition", explains that overload resolution would in fact consider `operator conversion-type-id ( )` where `conversion-type-id` denotes a function pointer or reference.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as name lookup "in the context of class `T`". The standard defines ([**\[basic.lookup\]/2**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#2)) the concept of "looked up in the context of an expression". Thus, the function call syntax `(E)(args)` is expanded to `(E).operator()(args`), and the name `operator()` is looked up in the context of this expression.

Comment: @Belloc: ADL is not relevant if `E` is of class type.  The parens are to avoid misinterpretation in cases like `(a.obj)(0)`, where the left parentheses have been [previously overlooked](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.paren#1).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Then `operator()` is looked up in the scope where `(E).operator()(args)` is found. But what is the scope where `(E).operator()(args)` is found?